# Paypal sandbox email validation fails when importing old test accounts

Tags: validation, email, import, paypal

I'm trying to import the old test accounts on the new paypal developer page, but it says that my email address is not valid. My email has the form of "fname.lname@provider.com". I think it is valid and it used to be. What has changed? Is there any way to get the old accounts back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this stupid regex on line 12888 in this file: https://www.paypalobjects.com/eboxapps/js/15/5b6c59feedeae95c484f296dc3b9de/main.js

```
var EMAIL_REGEX = new RegExp("^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-])*@[A-Za-z0-9--]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
```

It doesn't match . in the local part of the email address.

If you want to fix it using chrome devtools, put a breakpoint on that line, enter your email (which will trigger the breakpoint), then rightclick on the line and select "Live edit", then add a dot on the first matching group, like this: `[_A-Za-z0-9-.]` so it becomes this:

```
var EMAIL_REGEX = new RegExp("^[_A-Za-z0-9-.]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-])*@[A-Za-z0-9--]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
```

Hit Ctrl+S and click on "Resume script execution" (the little play icon on the right). Done.